# What causes "Unable to start service Intent"?

Tags: android

My app receives an intent from the C2DM servers to register for push notifications (which works fine), and on receiving that message through a broadcast receiver it starts an IntentService (to handle the intent received from C2DM). However the call to start that IntentService is failing with this:

```
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
cat=[com.company.myapp] cmp=com.company.myapp/.receiver.C2DMReceiver
(has extras) }: not found
```

Can you help me understand what this error means? The C2DMReceiver class is subclassed from IntentService, and it certainly exists. I am using Intent.setClass() and specifying the class directly. The compiler accepts it, so I do not understand why the exception is saying "Not found". What is not found?

If anyone can offer any tips on debugging this, I'd really appreciate it.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.company.myapp.receiver.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.company.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.company.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this was the  tag was missing from the manifest. Unfortunately it looks like I accidentally deleted it from the manifest, probably whilst making another edit. With the manifest entry there, the IntentService starts fine.

Comment: Which tag was missing? I get the same error maybe I made the same mistake.

Comment: <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" /> is the tag in question, where .GCMIntentService is the name of the class that extends GCMBaseIntentService. The tag must be inside your <application> tags.

Comment: Yes you are right Even i have accidently remove this service from AndroidMenifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered an Intent filter with action `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. The broadcast receiver works fine, it receives the message from C2DM, but what then fails is starting the IntentService.

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest to the question? At least the application block, to show how you used intent filter. Also a code sample on how you dispatched the intent.

Comment: Hmmm..try removing the second intent filter in your manifest, and move that intent filter's action to the first one. So that the first intent filter has two actions and one category

Comment: You're misunderstanding the problem. The broadcast receiver works just fine - it receives messages. The problem is in then starting up the IntentService subsequent to that.

Comment: Oh right, can you add in the service tag that you used to register your IntentService?

Comment: @OllieC let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2415/discussion-between-lightblade-and-ollie-c)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a device with android 2.2+ and Market app installed (meaning it's an official Google device).

Comment: I am. It's a Nexus One, they don't get much more official than that :) But as I have said the problem is not receiving push notification messages from the C2DM servers, that works fine, the problem is when the broadcast receiver tries to start the IntentService to process that message.